# Developing intuition on what difference between consecutive points means

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r, differences

As an example, let's take `var_a` and `var_b`:

`var_a <- c(0,10,10,9,12,10,10,0)`

`var_b <- c(5,7,6,5,7,7,8,7)`

All points are arranged in chronological order.

Within var_a, I calculate the difference between each value and the preceding one, so that:

`diff.var_a <- c(NA,10,0,-1,3,-2,0,-10)`

Then I do the same with `var_b`:

`diff.var_b <- c(NA,2,-1,-1,2,0,1,-1)`

The correlation between `var_a` and `var_b` is **0.35**, while the correlation between `diff.var_a` and `diff.var_b` is (remving the NAs) **0.75**.

What I would like to achieve is to show if variations in var_a are related to variations in var_b.

My initial idea was simply to calculate Pearson's r for `var_a` and `var_b`. Then I thought that maybe using the difference between consecutive points might do a better job in highlighting how changes in one variable correspond to changes in the other, hence the correlation between `diff.var_a` and `diff.var_b`.

The correlation coefficients are quite different, and can results in different interpretations. So now I am a bit stumped and I don't know a) if I should stick to a simple correlation between `var_a` and `var_b`, and b) what kind of information does the difference between consecutive points actually convey.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: "To show if variations in var_a are related to variations in var_b," you compare the variations to each other.  Comparing the original values of `var_a` and `var_b` does not address this question: it's irrelevant.

Comment: Your comment actually proved quite useful to understand better the situation, thanks